# OpenShift Hub Creation vs Create New Application

Tags: openshift, redhat

I just created an OpenShift free account.  When I logged in, I see there's a link called "Create new application".  Also, there's an OpenShift Hub where you deploy.

What's the difference between "Create new application" vs. creating it via OpenShift Hub? When do you use one way vs. the other?

Thanks

Comment: where did you find create "via OpenShiftHub" ?

Comment: On the Top Right Hand Side when you log into your account.  After you click on OpenShift Hub and select wildfly, you'll see the link "Deploy" but when I click on it, it shows the same screen as when you click on "Create Your First Application Now" link, 2nd step. I don't understand what's the difference between the two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

You should use whichever interface you prefer to search and research Carts, as you will arrive at the same place when you choose to deploy.

Like you say, from the "[Applications](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications)" Page there are two pages:

1. The "Create A New Application" Page

   If you click "[Create New Application](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types)" (or "[Add Application](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types)" if you already have apps), this is where you go. It lists various app kinds, and has a search function.
   Searching "Python" allows me to select and create a "[Python 3.3](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_type/cart!python-3.3)" cart.
2. OpenShift Hub

   If you click "[OpenShift Hub](https://hub.openshift.com/)", this is where you go. Again, searching for "Python" will reveal a [Python 3.3 Quickstart](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/103-python-3-3) that, as you mention, has a "[Deploy](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/deploy/103-python-3-3)" option on it.

When you click the "Deploy" link from `2`, you are redirected to [the exact same page](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_type/cart!python-3.3) as when you select the app from `1`. It is therefore strictly a matter of personal preference which interface you use. You may find using the "Hub" and its extra informational page helpful, or you might prefer to skip it if you know what you want.